# Can I use regex inside node js like this code?

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

```
  function isLetter(string) {
    if ( /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(string)) {
       return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

This is a code I wrote in my client side and works fun.
Now I wanna know can I use that in my server side as well? if no, how should I do that?

Comment: Why would you think you couldn't?

Comment: What is stopping you? Also `function isLetter(string) return  /^[a-zA-Z\s]*$/.test(string); }`

Comment: Both are JavaScript, so they both work -- no matter which side you run it on. Have you actually tried it in NodeJS to find out?

Comment: You likely could have tried it first, taking less time than not to know and post this question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use this function on the server as well without any modifications. It doesn't matter if it is the browser engine that executes the code or the node.js.

Comment: Thanks, I will use that.